# Puppet restarts services twice — can it be fixed?

Tags: puppet

When service is described with both `ensure => running` and subscribed to config file changes if both conditions fulfil (i.e. it is not running and config file changed) it gets (re)started *twice*. Is there a way to make it start only once?

To clarify, I have the following type:

```
    service { "puppet":
      ensure     => running,
      enable     => true,
      hasrestart => true,
      subscribe  => File["/etc/puppet/puppet.conf"],
    } # service
```

When **both** `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` is changed and service puppet is not running I see the following in puppet output (with --debug specified):

```
....
debug: /Stage[main]/Puppet/Service[puppet]/subscribe: subscribes to File[/etc/puppet/puppet.conf]
notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet/File[/etc/puppet/puppet.conf]/content: content changed '{md5}c39350dd1e135cf9fffd14ff167d6655' to '{md5}845a4aac5e83ab3f8cd9efd80ce17772'
....
info: /etc/puppet/puppet.conf: Scheduling refresh of Service[puppet]
debug: /etc/puppet/puppet.conf: The container Class[Puppet] will propagate my refresh event
info: /etc/puppet/puppet.conf: Scheduling refresh of Service[puppet]
debug: Service[puppet](provider=debian): Executing '/etc/init.d/puppet status'
debug: Service[puppet](provider=debian): Executing '/etc/init.d/puppet start'
notice: /Stage[main]/Puppet/Service[puppet]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
debug: /Stage[main]/Puppet/Service[puppet]: The container Class[Puppet] will propagate my refresh event
debug: Service[puppet](provider=debian): Executing '/etc/init.d/puppet status'
debug: Service[puppet](provider=debian): Executing '/etc/init.d/puppet restart'
err: /Stage[main]/Puppet/Service[puppet]: Failed to call refresh: Could not restart Service[puppet]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/puppet restart' returned 1:  at /etc/puppet/modules/puppet/manifests/init.pp:32
```

This obviously fails because of the following:

```
root:~# /etc/init.d/puppet restart ; /etc/init.d/puppet restart
 * Restarting puppet agent                                         [ OK ] 
 * Restarting puppet agent                                         [fail]
```

Is there a way to cope with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puppet IRC channel answered my question.

It is a bug of Puppet and it is described here:
http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/show/9656

Comment: Also see https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7165 which may be more relevant.

Comment: Yep, the ticket I've posted the link to is the dupe of your one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from my puppet install at the moment, but a couple of things:

1. What version of puppet are you running?
2. Funny things always happen to me when I forget to add 'hasstatus => true' to my services.  It may not fix your problem, but it shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: I'm using 2.7.3 deb package from puppetlabs apt repository.
Thank you for advice about hasstatus => true, I'll keep that in mind.